# Render visible voxel in 3D array without iterate it all

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, voxel

I'm doing a voxel engine and my data are in a 3D array per chunk. To render voxels, I need to know which one can be visible, so they will have `Air` block around it (0 in my data structure).

So I need to find all number which have a 0 beside in left, right, front, back, top and bot direction, but I really don't know how to do it.

I know I can do it with loop, but my goal is to achieve this task the fastest as I can.

For exemple (in 2D):

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
```

Must return me these indexes:

```
(1,1) (1,2) (1,3)
(2,1)       (2,3)
(3,1)             (3,4)
(4,1) (4,2) (4,3)
```

I want to have the index of the numbers which are at the edge of the array even if there is no 0 around, because I can then check in beside chunk if there is `Air` data.

I don't know if it is possible, and if it is not, how can I render visible voxel without iterate over all the array?

Thanks.

(Sorry for my english, send comment if you don't understand all)

**EDIT**
After reading @Mad_Physicist comment, I post my uncomplete method to achieve the task with a loop (I didn't finish it because I was searching for a fastest way instead):

```
matrix = numpy.zeros((10,10,10), dtype="uint8")

# Filling with some random data
for y in range(10):
    for z in range(10):
        for x in range(10):
            matrix[y, z, x] = random.choice((0,1,1)

result = numpy.transpose(numpy.where(matrix == 0))
for num in result.tolist():
    u = matrix.item(*num)
    # TODO: Check each direction
```

The weakness of this method is that I sometime pass throught useless data (0 with 0 in all directions).

Comment: Show how you do it with a loop at least.

Comment: Do you want indices or a mask? A mask would be much faster to compute and probably to work with after as well.

Comment: Please explain the criterion by which you accept `(4, 2)`

Comment: I want to have the index of the numbers which are at the edge of the array even if there is no 0 around, because I can then check in beside chunk if there is `Air` data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_erosion`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion.html#scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion):

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_erosion

np.argwhere(arr & ~binary_erosion(arr))
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 1],
       [4, 2],
       [4, 3]])
```

Comment: @Trytio I think so, but not 100% sure. Let me check. -- Yes, it does.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I have been searching for a day. And it is incredibly fast !

Comment: @PaulPanzer It'd be nice to hyperlink the pages so that readers can read more about the method than doing a search with the *ubiquitous search engine*.